# linear-gradient equivalent to moz-linear-gradient

Tags: css

I want to replace the following Mozilla-specific CSS rule:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F5F5F5, #E4E4E4);
```

with an equivalent rule that uses the standard `linear-gradient` instead. In other words, how can I complete the following rule so that it has the same effect (in Firefox) as the rule above

```
background: linear-gradient /* what goes here? */
```

Comment: Is your Google broken? Not trying to be a smart-alec, but if you google "Liner-Gradient" you will get about 5 million results.

Comment: Well, I typed `Linear-Gradient` into my Google. The first result is a link to documentation on `linear-gradient` - right under the heading `Syntax`. The second result is a gradient generator that will write that code for all browsers (Much like what Ron posted). As of today Google returned `About 10,500,000 results`. http://tinyurl.com/7yrvskk - Again, not trying to be a wise guy. Just seems silly to me to post a question before doing doing a superficial Google.

Comment: FF 14 still needs the prefix...-moz- or it fails.

Comment: https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/complete-guide-to-cross-browser-compatible-css-gradients/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle all gradients for all browsers, I hope this helps;

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some gradient generators if you are having some difficulties or just for speeding up the process.

**Examples**:
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
http://westciv.com/tools/gradients/
http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Answer (score 0):

`center` is not part of the linear gradient specification. (I don't know why it's ignored rather than being a CSS error.) The most up-to-date syntax supported by Firefox is `-moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #E4E4E4);` however as far as I know the specification hasn't reached CR status so this could still change.