# Linear-gradient works only with -moz vendor prefix

Tags: css, linear-gradients, vendor-prefix

Since this code works with the -moz vendor prefix I thought it would work a well with -webkit or -ms for instance, but it doesn't seem to allow it:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
```

I guess Mozilla is allowing something that shouldn't be used, but my research has been infructuous as of now...

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linear-gradient equivalent to moz-linear-gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323031/linear-gradient-equivalent-to-moz-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `center`. Then it should work.

Also make sure you have it for all browsers:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95) 100%);
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n2sf/)

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks a lot! On top of that, removing it with -moz vendor prefix didn't change a thing (I used an exemple to test it, that didn't explain that part). I am curious of what was the purpose of `center`.

Comment: center is strictly equivalent to 50% and top or left to 0% and right or bottom to 100%, as it is for `background-position` keywords. Thus http://jsfiddle.net/9n2sf/1/ (`-10% 0%`) will show you that it's some sort of origin/offset of your gradient. And direction, not orthogonal to an axis anymore. But it's ze olde syntax

Answer (score 0):

There's a new syntax for linear gradients where the first keyword is like `(to bottom, etc)`.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/H8Byj/

```
div {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom , rgba(0, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 255, 1) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 100%);
}
```

I didn't know the old syntax with prefix was still active in Firefox but the new one appeared circa Fx10-Fx15 according to Resources found at [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient).
[ColorZilla CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) will give you all the declarations needed for retro and multibrowser compatibility.

Comment: Great resource, thanks! I didn't think about adding something for IE 6 to 9.